# My React App is ignoring a standard html page that I created when I try to navigate to it

Tags: reactjs, entity-framework-core

I have a single page React web app frontend that loads the index.js file first.

It uses Entity Framework Core controllers on the backend to load/save data.

The index.js file loads another component called Header.js

It looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Header from "./Header/Header";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
    </React.Fragment>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

When I load the site, https://xmywebportalx.games.ca/, it automatically goes to the index.js and then loads the Header Component.

The app works fine, but I want to add a link to it from an offsite web page.

I want the link to be https://xmywebportalx.games.ca/tryForFree.html

The tryForFree.html is separate from the main React app and just adds an entry to the database via the backend Entity Framework Core.

So I created a tryForFree.html page to test, but every time I try to go there via the link, https://xmywebportalx.games.ca/tryForFree.html, it seems to be ignored because the app always just goes to the index.js then to the Header component.

How can I get the react app to load my https://xmywebportalx.games.ca/tryForFree.html link when it's hit by a browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you could get around this by reading the URL on page load and manually redirect to the HTML page if the path is `"/tryForFree.html"`.

Specifically, inside a `UseEffect` hook with an empty dependency array (so it runs only on initial page load), you can inspect the pathname of the URL with `window.location.pathname` and if it's equal to `"/tryForFree.html"`, load the html page.

Comment: Do you mean I should put `useEffect` inside the index.js `ReactDOM.render` part?  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell I should've been more specific. If `Header` is a functional component (otherwise you can't use hooks in it), you can put it in the code for `Header`. If it's not functional, just put it in the `componentDidMount` method.